# Using Razor, how do I render a Boolean to a JavaScript variable?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

How do I render a Boolean to a JavaScript variable in a cshtml file?

Presently this shows a syntax error:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >

    var myViewModel = {
        isFollowing: @Model.IsFollowing  // This is a C# bool
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 357, accepted):

You may also want to try:

```
isFollowing: '@(Model.IsFollowing)' === '@true'
```

and an ever better way is to use:

```
isFollowing: @Json.Encode(Model.IsFollowing)
```

Comment: `@Json.Encode(Model.IsFollowing)` is imho the most elegant solution. Thank you!

Comment: Normally there's going to be more than one boolean being used in which case encoding the whole model makes things nice and easy to use thereafter. eg:      **var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));** and then you can just call *model.IsFollowing*  (Sorry I don't know how to format the comment code properly)

Comment: Add `@using System.Web.Helpers` to complete the code.

Answer (score 79):

Because a search brought me here: in ASP.NET Core, `IJsonHelper` doesn't have an `Encode()` method.  Instead, use `Serialize()`. E.g.:

```
isFollowing: @Json.Serialize(Model.IsFollowing)
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning asp.net core!

Answer (score 31):

The JSON boolean must be lowercase.

Therefore, try this (and make sure nto to have the `//` comment on the line):

```
var myViewModel = {
    isFollowing: @Model.IsFollowing.ToString().ToLower()
};
```

Or (note: you need to use the namespace `System.Xml`):

```
var myViewModel = {
    isFollowing: @XmlConvert.ToString(Model.IsFollowing)
};
```

Comment: The .ToString() approach is probably the most efficient one. Using '@Model.IsFollowing.ToString().ToLowerInvariant()' must be a bit more efficient and somewhat more straightforward.

Comment: Using the method, to string and to lower is definitely the cleanest in my option as it reads nicely in javascript.

Answer (score 15):

```
var myViewModel = {
    isFollowing: '@(Model.IsFollowing)' == "True";
};
```

Why `True` and not `true` you ask... Good question:
[Why does Boolean.ToString output "True" and not "true"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/491334/601179)

Comment: Not to question it, but is the encoding of `@Model.IsFollowing` actually valid JS syntax?  Or is it relying on the fact that it will be because it happens to be boolean?

Comment: @Model.IsFollowing is razor syntax, not js

Comment: @gahooa, no it's not, it is parsed on the server with the Razor engine.

Comment: @Nikos, then try: `'@(Model.IsFollowing)'`

Comment: @Nikos, Did you try to run it? a lot of times it's just Visual Studio issue but it runs perfectly fine. Try running it!

Answer (score 12):

A solution which is easier to read would be to do this:

```
isFollowing: @(Model.IsFollowing ? "true" : "false")
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's another option to consider, using the !! conversion to boolean.

```
isFollowing: !!(@Model.IsFollowing ? 1 : 0)
```

This will generate the following on the client side, with 1 being converted to true and 0 to false.

```
isFollowing: !!(1)  -- or !!(0)
```

Comment: minor correction !!@(Model.IsFollowing ? 1 : 0) works great

Answer (score 0):

[Defining a conversion operation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators) and adding an override of `.ToString()` can save a lot of work.

Define this `struct` in your project:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// A <see cref="bool"/> made for use in creating Razor pages.
/// When converted to a string, it returns "true" or "false".
/// </summary>
public struct JSBool
{
    private readonly bool _Data;

    /// <summary>
    /// While this creates a new JSBool, you can also implicitly convert between the two.
    /// </summary>
    public JSBool(bool b)
    {
        _Data = b;
    }

    public static implicit operator bool(JSBool j) => j._Data;
    public static implicit operator JSBool(bool b) => new JSBool(b);

    // Returns "true" or "false" as you would expect
    public override string ToString() => _Data.ToString().ToLowerInvariant();
}
```

### Usage

You can directly cast a C# `bool`, as in the case of the question:

```js
{
    // Results in `isFollowing : true`
    isFollowing : @((JSBool)Model.IsFollowing)
}
```

But you can also use a `JSBool` directly in the Razor code with the expectation that it will give `true` and `false` without having to do any extra work:

```
@{
    JSBool isA = true;
    JSBool isB = false;
    // Standard boolean operations work too:
    JSBool isC = a || b;
}

<script>
    if (@isC)
        console.log('true');
</script>
```

This works because of the implicit conversion operators we defined above.

---

Just make sure to only ever use this when you intend to use it in Razor code. In other words, don't use it with normal C# as this can make your code messy.