# How can I pass a Razor boolean variable to an Angular directive?

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, razor, boolean

I have a boolean variable in my cshtml file. When I try to pass it to my Angular directive, it is received as "False" instead of "false". If I hardcode it to "false" (lower case), it does not work either.

My cshtml file:

```
@{
    var myVar = false;
}

<some-directive test="@myVar"></some-directive>
```

My test directive is like this:

```
angular.module('someApp')
  .directive('someDirective', function () {
      return {
          restrict: 'E',
          scope: {
              test: '@'
          },
          link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {

              console.log($scope.test) // False
              console.log(!$scope.test) // false
              console.log(!!$scope.test) // true
          }
      }
  });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find part of your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14448604/using-razor-how-do-i-render-a-boolean-to-a-javascript-variable).

Specifically for Angular, use the directive variable as `test: '='` instead of `test: '@'`. With this, your variable will be parsed as a **boolean** with the value "false" and not as the **text** "false".

Also, in your Razor file, try the following to convert from "False" to "false":

```
@{
    var myRazorVar = false;
}

<some-directive test="@myRazorVar.ToString().ToLower()"></some-directive>
@* or *@
<some-directive test="@Json.Encode(myRazorVar)"></some-directive>
```

Comment: If you're using a function that returns True or False, I was able to use the above just with 

`<my-directive my-boolean="@MyFunctionReturnsTrue().ToString().Tolower()"></my-directive>` 
as well.

Comment: It does work but seems weird that you need to cast it to a string and then to lower to make the directive understand that its a boolean value. Surely there's a way to just send the boolean? Even 6 years later it does not seem straightforward!

Answer (score 3):

Since both languages are case sensitive and uses different pattern for Boolean (even for numbers) you can use:

```
<some-directive test="@Json.Encode(myVar)"></some-directive>
```

Will format C# data to javascript accordingly.

Comment: However, I'm pretty sure that you also need to use the `=` binding. Using `@` will treat the boolean as a string.

Answer (score 1):

your scope should be '=' not '@'

```
angular.module('someApp')
  .directive('someDirective', function () {
      return {
          restrict: 'E',
          scope: {
              test: '='
          },
          link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {

              console.log($scope.test) // false
              console.log(!$scope.test) // true
              console.log(!!$scope.test) // false
          }
      }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working like this:

```
let replicateReopeningClientFiles = @Json.Serialize(Model.ReplicateReopeningClientFiles);
```