Toggle hidden text based on variables
I have multiple texts which I want to display based on the input from a form from the previous page.
For example, if their answer meets certain criteria, in the controller I would make the TestEligibilty = True and if it doesn't TestEligibility = False. and I would add it to viewbag.
ViewBag.TestEligibility = TestEligbility;
I have tried this:
If variable = true, display a text and if variable = false, hide the text
    <div class ="Test-view">
        <p>-test successful</p>
    </div>        

This is what I put in my code below
<script>
    var TestEligibility = @ViewBag.TestEligibility;
    if (TestEligibility = false) {
        $('#Test-view').hide();
    }
    else {
        $('#Test-view').show();
    }
    
</script>


I think the problems are:

= is an assignment, you need === for comparison
# is the ID selector, you need . for class

<script>
    var TestEligibility = @ViewBag.TestEligibility;
    if (TestEligibility === false) {
        $('.Test-view').hide();
    }
    else {
        $('.Test-view').show();
    }
    
</script>

Or...
<script>
    $('.Test-view').toggle('@ViewBag.TestEligibility' === '@true')
</script>


My class does not go hidden even when TestEligibility is false, do you know how to fix it?

I think you have to convert the C# values to JavaScript like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20420176/22381889

Ok, thank you I found out the reason why my code is not working, when u store a value as a boolean in cs it auto reads out capitalise, so I had to convert it to a string and lower it so that Javascript understands it as true not True

If you wish to check two values are strictly equal, you could use strict equality ===.
