# String was not recognized as a valid boolean

Tags: c#, formatexception

I am sending the string representation of a boolean through a socket and reading it the other end.

```
void Send(bool value)
{
    Socket.Send(value.ToString());
}

void Receive()
{
    string message = Socket.Receive();

    Console.WriteLine(message) // Always equal to either 'True' or 'False (without quotes)

    bool result = bool.Parse(message) // here I get the format exception.
}
```

but I get the following exception when I try and parse my `message`:

> `String was not recognized as a valid boolean`.

The value when I get the exception is: `True`. With NO whitespace.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that is what is what is received? I'd be stunned if you had found a genuine bug in the framework - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.boolean.parse.aspx

Comment: What is the value of message _when you get the exception?_

Comment: Do you have any special characters in your message?

Comment: Try converting the String to lower case first. See this post for details [Why does Boolean.ToString output “True” and not “true”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/491334/why-does-boolean-tostring-output-true-and-not-true)

Comment: No I print it out, along with the length of the message. Literally all I am sending is `True` or `False`...I check both before and after the Socket the length of the string and the string itself.

Comment: @ErenErsönmez: Look at the question (code comment)

Comment: Already tried converting to lowercase, also uppercase. Neither worked.

Comment: Try to check with `String.Compare(message, Boolean.TrueString, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);` and `String.Compare(message, Boolean.FalseString, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);`. If both return false, check char by char to find differences.

Comment: Following the MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.boolean.parse.aspx) this shouldn't be the problem

Comment: There must be an issue with your message string. Are you sure that it is definitely "true" or "false"??

Comment: What about Convert.ToBool()?

Comment: Try `bool.Parse("True")` and see if you still get a formatexception? If you don't, then your received message is not exactly "True"...

Comment: I would take a look in the debugger at what the receive string contains - or better still in a watch window put message.ToCharArray() and see if there are any "special" characters in there.  Sometimes I've seen control chars in strings that don't print out but are still there.

Comment: @defaultlocale the string compare with Boolean.TrueString returns 0.

Comment: @Ben is there any code in between `String.Compare` and `Boolean.Parse` calls? if the answer is "yes", then comment it out and try again, otherwise, please, tell us .net framework version details.

Comment: you could do something like this bool result = bool.Parse(message == "True" ? "true" : "false");

Comment: @MrPurpleStreak no special characters.

Comment: @defaultlocale There are no calls. .Net 4.0

Comment: @KevDevMan I could, but that's not the point, I don't want to have to do that!

Comment: @Ben, what does `Boolean.Parse(Boolean.TrueString)` return?

Comment: @defaultlocale returns a boolean with value true.

Comment: I've narrowed down the problem. When linking to the library external to the solution I am working on I get the problem...but when I create a test bed within the solution I DON'T get an issue. The library I am linking to is ABSOLUTELY unequivocally the latest build - NO DOUBT WHAT SO EVER about that.

Comment: you said the value for the `message` is `True`,i wanted to know whether it is `true` or `True`.

Comment: `bool.Parse` should be able to parse `true`, `True`, `trUe`, or even `trUe                `. I would try parsing a constant string that has the same value that you think the variable has, and then compare that string with the variable. Either your `bool.Parse` is not working as expected, or the variable does not have the value that you think it does (or that it appears to have).

Comment: What kind of `Socket` are you using? Is it `System.Net.Sockets.Socket`?

Comment: I didn't realize this was 2 years old...

Answer (score 1):

At first glance, I would consider it having an issue with untrimmed space..., but that's not the case, as `Boolean.Parse` uses `TryParse` and that, in turn, trims the space in one of its attempts:

```
public static Boolean Parse (String value) {
    if (value==null) throw new ArgumentNullException("value");
    Contract.EndContractBlock();
    Boolean result = false;
    if (!TryParse(value, out result)) {
        throw new FormatException(Environment.GetResourceString("Format_BadBoolean"));            
    }
    else {
        return result;
    }
}

public static Boolean TryParse (String value, out Boolean result) {
    result = false;
    if (value==null) {
        return false;
    }
    // For perf reasons, let's first see if they're equal, then do the
    // trim to get rid of white space, and check again.
    if (TrueLiteral.Equals(value, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
        result = true;
        return true;
    }
    if (FalseLiteral.Equals(value,StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
        result = false;
        return true;
    }

    // Special case: Trim whitespace as well as null characters.
    value = TrimWhiteSpaceAndNull(value);

    if (TrueLiteral.Equals(value, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
        result = true;
        return true;
    }

    if (FalseLiteral.Equals(value,StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
        result = false;
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

**Reference:** http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/boolean.cs,e2a8f2e50ecf93c0,references

So, there must be something else going on.  Perhaps there is an issue with the format, UTF-8, ANSI, ASCII, etc. One of your requirements is that you want a bool, so that you won't have two cases for `True` and `False`, so why not do something like this:

```
bool result = message.ToLower().Contains("true"); // true or false
```

**EDIT:**

After reading some of the comments, it seems you're expecting cases beyond `True` or `False`, in which case the result could be invalid.  I suggest something like this:

```
var lMessage = message.ToLower();
bool? result = lMessage.Equals("true") ? true : lMessage.Equals("false") ? false : null;
```

So, if the message contains `True`, it's `true`; if `False`, it's `false`; otherwise, it's `null`, which indicates an invalid message.  You can then check to see if `result` is `null` and either display the invalid message or do something else.  I'm not sure what your routine is from there on.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
void Receive()
{
    string message = Socket.Receive();

    Console.WriteLine(message) // Always equal to either 'True' or 'False (without quotes)

    bool result = message.ToLower().Equals("true");
}
```

Comment: Obviously this would work, but I'd prefer to use bool.Parse otherwise I have to have another case for false.

Comment: No, if message is "False" then user2004810 's solution will still pass. bool.Parse is not required.

Comment: The method Equals("true") already return true/false, you no  need another case.

Comment: @Ben can't you suppose that all that is not true is false ?

Comment: @tschmit007 how is "NotFalse" equal to "False"?

Comment: @tschmit007 No NotTrue != False, you can have an invalid message also.