# Convert.ToBool(string, IFormatProvider) disregards IFormatProvider

Tags: c#, .net, base-class-library

So [it appears](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17602168/parse-boolean-c-sharp-culture-verdadero) that `Convert.ToBoolean(string, IFormatProvider)` completely ignores the given `IFormatProvider`.

[ReferenceSource](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs,447) seems to agree:

```
public static bool ToBoolean(String value, IFormatProvider provider) {
    if (value == null)
        return false;
    Boolean.Parse(value);
}
```

but, despite this, <strike>the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yxtzk8k8(v=vs.110).aspx) advertises the behavior one would expect</strike>. **No, this is not true: as @tyranid pointed out, I'm going blind.**

Digging further, there exists the `Convert.ToBoolean(object, IFormatProvider)` overload, which invokes `IConvertible.ToBoolean(IFormatProvider)` on the given value. Bingo, right? Just box the value and you're golden.

Sadly, though, `System.String`'s implementation of that method is as follows:

```
bool IConvertible.ToBoolean(IFormatProvider provider) {
    return Convert.ToBoolean(this, provider);
}
```

so we're back to where we started.

This seems like a huge oversight in a framework that otherwise is generally coherent.

Maybe it's a harder problem that one would imagine?

More importantly: do any of you know of a workaround? Is one supposed to handle all the different possible truthy and falsy values with a huge `switch`?

Oddly enough, either my Google-fu is getting rusty, or this issue has not been debated much.

Comment: I remember spelunking in ReferenceSource to the Convert class (long time ago) and finding out that some parameter was being ignored (I can't remember if this was the function I found, but I do remember it was Convert). So you are not alone. I can only guess, that trying to "fix" this bug could potentially break code that relied on this "broken" behavior.

Comment: The page you linked explicitly states for the provider "An object that supplies culture-specific formatting information. This parameter is ignored." so seems it is documented, just badly.

Comment: @tyranid thanks, edited the question. I guess there's nothing to do then. Write an answer for posterity if you want, I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: Converting text to a boolean value is a pain in the ass to begin with. In our code bases, I'm pretty obstinate about using `"1" == value` and leaving it at that. Occasionally someone complains and demands that I support `true` -- no guesses for how I do that. I prefer predictability to the vagaries of `Convert`, especially for something specialized like `Boolean` (which innocent end users would be expected to enter only very rarely, and then not in a locale-specific format).