# true instead of True (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

### The goal

Return `true` instead of `True` from Controller to View.

### The problem

I'm storing into a variable a boolean that indicates whether a product exists or not in a shopping cart/summary.

To achieve this, I'm doing the following:

```
[...]
IsAdded = sessionStore.CheckExistanceOnSummary(product.productId)
[...]
```

But, when I show the value of `IsAdded` on the View, the return is `True` or `False` — and JavaScript is expecting `true` or `false`.

What I need is to send `true` or `false` instead of this way that C# is sending.

### What I've already tried

I already tried to change the above's code fragment into this:

```
IsAdded = (sessionStore.CheckExistanceOnSummary(product.productId) ? 
    "true" : 
    "false")
```

But debugger returns me the following error:

> Error 5   Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool'

### A few lines of code

The implementation of `CheckExistanteOnSummary` is:

```
public bool CheckExistanceOnSummary(Nullable<int> productId)
{
    List<Products> productsList = 
        (List<Products>)Session[summarySessionIndex];

    if (productsList.Where
        (product => product.id == (int)productId).FirstOrDefault() == null)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

### Duplicated?

I read [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491334/why-does-boolean-tostring-output-true-and-not-true), but didn't not help me.

Comment: Make IsAdded a string then...

Comment: +1 just for the complete explain question! Use the @Matt Houser solution, I also have this problem with razor view engine and javascript.

Comment: In javascript, `"1" == true` (don't use triple equals) so you could just return a string "1" or "0" instead.

Comment: dhsto's answer is often useful in a (totally separate, but I'll bring it up anyway) case where you want to minimize the JSON you throw at a view. I often have a json parsing as 1's and 0's rather than "true" and "false". Saves a significant amount of space

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As a boolean (`bool`), the values will always be "True" or "False". If you want to represent these differently when converted to a string, you can do the following in your view:

```
@Model.IsAdded.ToString().ToLower()
```

Comment: This. Or, something like " ('@(Model.IsAdded)' == 'True') when evaluating.

Comment: Wow! Too simple solution. I think it was my fault. I need to pay more attention to the type. Thanks, Matt!

Answer (score 4):

This will not work as IsAdded is boolean and "true" is string

```
IsAdded = (sessionStore.CheckExistanceOnSummary(product.productId) ? 
    "true" : 
    "false")
```

Try using it in javascript by converting it toLowercase().

Answer (score 4):

You could create a Display Template for bool that is "true"/"false" for reusability purposes:

1. Create a Display Template called "JsBoolean.cshtml":
2. In your view, use `@Html.DisplayFor()` and specify your new template.

**JsBoolean.cshtml:**

```
@model Boolean

@(Model ? "true" : "false")
```

**In your view:**

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.IsAdded, "JsBoolean")
```

Using this scheme, you have added "reusability" to your views for javascript purposes. You could also use this (if needed) to make booleans display as "yes" or "no" or something else.

**Edit:**

If your boolean values will **always** be lowercase, then you can make your custom view the default one by calling it "Boolean.cshtml".  Then you can simplify your use to:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.IsAdded)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add an extra read-only property (for example jsIsAdded) which returns IsAdded.ToString().ToLower().

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could incorporate the following code:

```
IsAdded.ToString().ToLower();
```

Sort of like this:

```
public string JSCheckExistanceOnSummary(Nullable<int> productId)
{
    return  CheckExistanceOnSummary(productId).ToString().ToLower();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you use a bit instead? 0 or 1
this way no matter the langage. Also most of the the bool is most likely a bit (check sql for example)