# Why String.Concat returns 'True' instead of 'true' (the same with false)?

Tags: c#, .net, boxing, unboxing

I'm studying **boxing** and **unboxing** topic from *C# 5.0 in a Nutshell by Joseph Albahari and Ben Albahari. Copyright 2012 Joseph Albahari and Ben Albahari, 978-1-449-32010-2*, but I need to extend the deep of knowledge and I found the MSDN article: [Boxing and Unboxing (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx), on it I found this example code (evidently not intrinsically related to the main topic):

```
Console.WriteLine (String.Concat("Answer", 42, true));
```

Once executed it returns:

```
Answer42True
```

Why this is happening with the literal 'true' (the same occurs with 'false')?

[Execution test](http://ideone.com/gLaqDY).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @SonerGönül not sure that's the same question... It might be the *next* question.

Comment: @AntP This is exactly same question. Since `String.Concat` converts them to string, the real point will be why `true.ToString()` is `True` not `true`.

Comment: No, it's not the same question, because the asker doesn't necessarily *know* that String.Concat converts its parameters to a string. So the answer to this question is "because String.Concat converts its parameters to a string and you're passing it a bool." Hence the *next* question might be as linked. You're jumping the gun.

Comment: The other question is most abstract, it serves as base to explain many of the facts (behavior of the String.ToString method, for example) of the mine. So, for my point of view, they aren't (precisely) the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the sample  reason if you  try to decompile  `String.Concat()` method  in mscorlib.dll 
you will get something  like this

```
      for (int index = 0; index < args.Length; ++index)
      {
        object obj = args[index];
        values[index] = obj == null ? string.Empty : obj.ToString(); //which  will call the `ToString()` of `boolean struct` 

      }
```

`ToString()`  method which  is called by default  by `string.Concat` method it is like this

```
 public override string ToString()
    {
      return !this ? "False" : "True";
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

This is because....

```
true.ToString() == "True"
```

And `String.Concat` must convert its arguments to strings, while `true` is a bool!

Answer (score 3):

Takea look at first of all: [Why does Boolean.ToString output "True" and not "true"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491334/why-does-boolean-tostring-output-true-and-not-true)

There is no `String.Concat(string, int, bool)` overload, that's why your code calls nearest overload which is `String.Concat(object, object, object)`.

And [`String.Concat(Object arg0, Object arg1, Object arg2)`](http://referencesource-beta.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs#e7f761c274d2036b#references) method implemented like this;

```
public static String Concat(Object arg0, Object arg1, Object arg2)
{
        if (arg0 == null)
        {
            arg0 = String.Empty;
        }

        if (arg1==null) {
            arg1 = String.Empty;
        }

        if (arg2==null) {
            arg2 = String.Empty;
        }

        return Concat(arg0.ToString(), arg1.ToString(), arg2.ToString());
}
```

As you can see, all objects convert to string at the last line.

That's why your code works like this;

```
String.Concat("Answer", 42.ToString(), true.ToString()));
```

And it will be;

```
String.Concat("Answer", "42", "True"));
```

And result will be;

```
Answer42True
```

Answer (score 2):

`true` is not a string. The framework must convert `true` or `false` into strings before concatenating them to the string, and it just so happens that the way that conversion is defined for them is that the first letter is capitalized.