# How can I check if TempData is null through integration with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, toastr

I would like to show a `toastr` (aka a popup) if `TempData` isn't null.  However, I'm having trouble integrating the jQuery and Razor syntax together.  This is my current javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        if (@TempData["SuccessMessage"] != null) {
            toastr.options = {
                "closeButton": true,
                "positionClass": "toast-bottom-right"
            }
            toastr.success("This is a test!");
        }
});
```

However, the toastr isn't displaying.  I'm already checking TempData further up to also display text to the user.

```
@if (TempData["SuccessMessage"] != null)
{
    <div class="success-message">
        @Html.Raw(@TempData["SuccessMessage"].ToString())
    </div>
}
```

I'm wondering if an alternative would be to somehow use the above markup and just check if this div exists, and if so, show the toastr?  Or perhaps I can integrate the two checks into one?  Suggestions?

Comment: have you looked at the generated markup? my guess is that you have `if ( != null) {`, which is obviously invalid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to get it working with the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var success = @((TempData["SuccessMessage"] != null).ToString().ToLower());

    if (success == true) {
        toastr.options = {
            "closeButton": true,
            "positionClass": "toast-bottom-right"
        }
        toastr.success("Success!  You're now registered for Lose A Ton!");
    }
});
```

For anyone curious, I had to call `ToLower()` because TempData would always return `True` or `False`, rather than `true` or `false`.  The reasons for this are explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491334/why-does-boolean-tostring-output-true-and-not-true).

Comment: Just for reference, you can set the options of a specific toast by suppling the options as the third argument of the toast.success function.

Answer (score 5):

you should do something like

```
if (@(TempData["SuccessMessage"] == null ? "null" : ('"' + TempData["SuccessMessage"] + '"')) != null) {
```

so that the generated markup in case TempDate is null will be

```
if (null != null) {
```

Comment: @JacobRoberts how? `null != null` is false, and `"foo" != null` is true. he would actually have to surround the TempData[] expression with quotes so it's a string in client code. fixing.

Comment: You are right `null != null` is false but your statement with the ternary operator is always going to make that statement true becuase `"null" != null` is true and `TempData["SuccessMessage"] != null` is always going to be true as well because if it was null, you are setting it to `"null"` with the ternary.

Comment: @JacobRoberts the ternary doesn't set TempData, it only reads it. What I tried to achieve here (haven't run it of course) is to print `null` to the client if `TempData["SuccessMessage"]` is null and the value of `TempData["SuccessMessage"]` as a string if it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

TempData Value in Jquery shown below.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var tempdataval = '@TempData["Value"]';
    if (tempdataval != null && tempdataval != '') {
        alert(tempdataval);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your java in `<text></text>` to tell Razor that it isn't c#, but inside a c# block

```
@if (TempData["SuccessMessage"] != null)
{
<text>
toastr.options = {
            "closeButton": true,
            "positionClass": "toast-bottom-right"
        }
        toastr.success("This is a test!");
</text>
}
```

You can also convert `@(TempData["SuccessMessage"] != null)` into a javascript bool and then use a javascript if statement, like so...

```
var hasSuccessMsg = @(TempData["SuccessMessage"] != null) === 'true';
if (hasSuccessMsg) {
    //do your work here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@if (TempData["SuccessMessage"] != null) {
    <script>
       $(document).ready(function() {
            toastr.options = {
                "closeButton": true,
                "positionClass": "toast-bottom-right"
            }
            toastr.success("This is a test!");     
      });
   </script>
 }
```