# how to check the value received from controller is not null in view in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

this is my controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Validate(HttpPostedFileBase excelfile)
    {
        if(excelfile==null || excelfile.ContentLength==0)
        {
            TempData["Message"] = "Please select a excel file";
            return View("Index");

       }
```

From here i am passing a  `TempData["Message"]` to view.how to check whether `TempData["Message"]` is not null in view ?

And in my view i am using `<script> @TempData["Message"]</script>` to  give a alert

Comment: check this..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30057854/how-can-i-check-if-tempdata-is-null-through-integration-with-jquery

Answer (score 1):

you can use:

```
@if (TempData["Message"] != null)
    {
      @TempData["Message"].ToString()
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this ,it will fix your issue

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var success = @((TempData["Message"] != null).ToString().ToLower());

if (success == true) {
        //Do your code here
  }
});
```