# Using bool from model in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have jQuery function in my view.

And variable in my view model:

```
public bool pageChanged { get; set; }
```

Function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (@Model.pageChanged == true) {
        $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#picture_section").offset().top
        }, 2000);
    }
});
```

Without if statement it works fine. But if I want to compare bool value of my model it doesn't work. I tried alert("@Model.pageChanged") and it showed right value.

So I tried

```
if(@Model.pageChanged) {
}

if(@Model.pageChanged == true) {
}
```

But it didn't work. How could I change the if statement to work? Is there problems with types?

Thank you for solving issue.

Comment: If you want to get an mvc object in jquery, use `'@Model.pageChanged'`

Comment: `if (@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@Model.pageChanged )) == true) { ... }` (or just `if (@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@Model.pageChanged))) { ... }`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thank you. It works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So there are boundaries between the client and server that are potentially in play.  The model code within a view, in the context you have it, essentially determines what gets rendered to the view.  So if you have this:

```
if (@Model.pageChanged == true) {
```

The server-side code renders the value of pageChanged to the client, except I found there are issues with rendering false.  A common workaround was:

```
if (@Model.pageChanged.ToString().ToLower() == true) {
```

Which will render:

```
if (true == true) {
```

OR

```
if (false == true) {
```

So you don't necessarily need the "== true" part.

If you want to control what JS actually gets rendered, you can do:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    @if (Model.pageChanged == true) {
        <text>
         $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#picture_section").offset().top
         }, 2000);
        </text>
    }
});
```

This text:

```
@if (Model.pageChanged == true) {
```

Becomes a server-side evaluation and determines whether the jQuery animate statement event renders at all, based on the value of pageChanged.

Comment: Thank you. It solved it, but why there must be the <text> </text> marks? Without them it didn´t work.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could do something like this:

```
if ("@Model.pageChanged" == "True") {...}
```

Here is the link to explain why "True" not "true": 
[Why does Boolean.ToString output "True" and not "true"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491334/why-does-boolean-tostring-output-true-and-not-true)