# Validating input field based on radio input and display error message

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to display a error message using jQuery while submitting the form, when radio button is selected true and input box is empty, for some reason its failing. Any suggestions are appreciated!

```
<div class="row col-lg-offset-2 top-buffer">
<h4>
    <strong>
        <span>Is Account Deleted?:</span>
    </strong>
</h4>
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsDeleted, true) @Html.Label("Yes")
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsDeleted, false) @Html.Label("No")

<br>
</div>
<div class="row col-lg-offset-2 top-buffer" id="reason">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <b>Reason for Delete:</b>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.reason, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "reason" })

        <br />
    </div>
    <div class="row col-sm-12">
        <label id="lblErrorMsg" class="has-error" style="color: #BD362F"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <button type = "submit" id="Next" name="Next" class="btn btn-primary">Next</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
<script>
$("#Next").click(function () {
    if ($("input[name='IsDeleted']" === "True" && $("#reason").val(''))) {
        $("#lblErrorMsg").text("Please enter meter number");
    } else {
        $("#lblErrorMsg").text("");
    }
});
```

Comment: try `true` not True, also is your reason but actually building?

Comment: Use a conditional validation attribute (refer the comment on your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46181191/hide-display-a-input-field-based-on-value-from-htmlradiobuttonfor-and-make-it-ma))

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks for the link, It was really helpful. But i'm trying to perform this validation in the view. which one is better to do? This approach works as well.

Comment: Your approach is awful. A conditional validation attribute works on both the client and the server (and the server side validation is what is important - client side validation is just a nice bonus but anyone can easily override it). Apply a `[RequiredIf("IsDeleted", true, ErrorMessage = "Please enter meter number")]` to your `reason` property and add `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.reason)` in the view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't be sure since I don't see full html code but try instead of:

```
if ($("input[name='IsDeleted']" === "True" && $("#reason").val(''))) {
```

this:

```
if ($("input[name='IsDeleted']:checked").val() === "True" && $("#reason").val() == '')
```

improved answer a bit, but make sure that IsDeleted radio button has Value "True"

Comment: Glad to be helpful, can you make sure my improved answer works as well?