# String.Replace() with a boolean value?

Tags: c#

I have a `Dictionary<string,dynamic>` of key value pairs.

I also have a string `script` in which I need to replace all occurrences of the key with corresponding value from the dictionary.

Eg : Contents of Dictionary :

```
Param1 : true
Param2 : "False"
Param3 : 123
Param4 : "1234"
```

`String script = " I have Param1 and Param2 and Param3 and Param4 "`.

Now I wish to convert it to

```
script = " I have true and "False" and 123 and "1234" "
```

How can I achieve this ? I have tried `script.Replace()` but it doesn't work for datatypes other than `string` and if I use `ToString()` for others , its capitalizing the `Boolean` values.

Edit : I also went through this link [Why does Boolean.ToString output "True" and not "true"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491334/why-does-boolean-tostring-output-true-and-not-true).

Comment: `script = " I have true and "False" and 123 and "1234" "` is not valid C#. A string cannot contain non-string values.

Comment: Actually , I need the output for a JSON Object so that's not an issue.

Comment: Can I ask why case matters only for param1? the logical step would be to just call `ToLower`

Comment: Lets say that Param1 is a `Boolean` value and Param2 and Param4 are `string` and Param3 is an `int`. `ToLower` is fine, but its a `string` function and I will get extra quotes when I use it on Param1.

Comment: `ToLower` does not create quotes, you should create an [mcve]

Comment: Why `Dictionary<string, dynamic>` and not `Dictionary<string, string>` or `Dictionary<string, object>` or even `Dictionary<string, Func<string>>`?

Comment: You've said *"I need the output for a JSON Object"*, so this is an XY problem and you need to show us the wider context, because to quote from the question you linked... "ToString is the major formatting method in the .NET Framework. It converts an object to its string representation so that it is suitable for **display**.". Object.ToString is not a **serialization** mechanism.

Comment: @Enigmativity If it is `Dictionary <string ,string>` , I will  not be able to differentiate between a `string "true"` and a `bool true` , as both will have same representation i.e. `"true"`.

Comment: @VaradBhatnagar - No, they wouldn't. `new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "Param1", "true" }, { "Param2", "\"False\"" }, };`

Comment: @VaradBhatnagar `Boolean.ToString()` returns result capitalized, because if you look at source code of `Boolean.ToString()`, it returns `return TrueLiteral;` if its value is `true` and `TrueLiteral` is declared like this: `internal const String TrueLiteral  = "True";`. **[boolean.cs](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/boolean.cs,f1b135ff6c380b37)**.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a go:

```
var map = new Dictionary<string, object>()
{
    { "Param1", true },
    { "Param2", "False" },
    { "Param3", 123 },
    { "Param4", "1234" },
};

var script = " I have Param1 and Param2 and Param3 and Param4 ";

var output = map.Aggregate(script,
    (s, kvp) => s.Replace(kvp.Key, kvp.Value is string ? $"\"{kvp.Value}\"" : kvp.Value.ToString()));
```

That gives the equivalent of:

```
var output = " I have True and \"False\" and 123 and \"1234\" ";
```

You may just need a .`ToLower()` in there.

Answer (score 0):

With `RegularExpressions` using the pattern `"Param\\d+"` you can use `String.Relace()` with the found matches.  You would have to check if the value from your map is of type `bool` so you can `String.ToLower()` for your desired result.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var map = new Dictionary<string, object>()
        {
            { "Param1", true },
            { "Param2", "\"False\"" },
            { "Param3", 123 },
            { "Param4", "\"1234\"" },
        };

        var script = " I have Param1 and Param2 and Param3 and Param4 ";
        MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(script, "Param\\d+");
        foreach (Match match in matches)
        {
            object val = map[match.Value];
            script = script.Replace(match.Value, val is bool ? val.ToString().ToLower() : val.ToString());
        }

        Console.WriteLine(script);
    }
}
```

Result:

```
 I have true and "False" and 123 and "1234"
```

[Fiddle Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9G4l0a)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in following way.

```
Boolean x = false;
Dictionary<string, dynamic> k = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>();
k.Add("Param1", x.ToString().ToLower());
k.Add("Param2", 123);
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("hi {0} -- {1}", k.Values.ToArray()));
```