# JavaScript is not playing nice with boolean false

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

In my partial view, I have a model that has boolean properties that I will pass to JavaScript functions.

```
namespace GbngWebClient.Models
{
   public class LikeOrDislikeVM
   {
    // Auto-implemented properties.

    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int LikeCount { get; set; }
    public int DisLikeCount { get; set; }
    public bool LikeDisabled { get; set; }
    public bool DisLikeDisabled { get; set; }
   }
}
```

[image]

I pass the model boolean properties to JavaScript functions as such.

```
@model GbngWebClient.Models.LikeOrDislikeVM

<style>
.fa {
    cursor: pointer;
    user-select: none;
}

    .fa:hover {
        color: blue;
    }

/* I added. */
.my-size {
    font-size: 20px;
}
</style>

@* Use the values that were passed via a model. *@
<div class="row">
<p><span class="blogLike my-size fa fa-thumbs-up"></span><span class="my-size"> : @Model.LikeCount</span> <span class="my-size"> | </span><span class="blogDisLike my-size fa fa-thumbs-down"></span><span class="my-size"> : @Model.DisLikeCount</span></p>
</div>

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log('Here at document ready');
    console.log('@Model.LikeDisabled');
    console.log('@Model.DisLikeDisabled');

    SetLike('@Model.LikeDisabled');
    SetDisLike('@Model.DisLikeDisabled');

    $('.blogLike').on('click', function () {
        alert('Here at like');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("SetBlogLikeOrDisLike", "BlogPublished")',
            data: { likeOrDislikeVM: @Model, likeOrDislikeIndicator: "L"},
            success: function (response) {

            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert("Critical Error: something is wrong in the call to SetBlogLikeOrDisLike for a Like! Status: " + xhr.status + ". Error: " + thrownError.toString() + ". Response Text: " + xhr.responseText);
            }
        })
    });

    $('.blogDisLike').on('click', function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("SetBlogLikeOrDisLike", "BlogPublished")',
            data: { likeOrDislikeVM: @Model, likeOrDislikeIndicator: "D"},
            success: function (response) {

            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert("Critical Error: something is wrong in the call to SetBlogLikeOrDisLike for a DisLike! Status: " + xhr.status + ". Error: " + thrownError.toString() + ". Response Text: " + xhr.responseText);
            }
        })
    });

    function SetLike(disabledSwitch) {
        //alert('Here at SetLike');
        console.log('Here at SetLike');
        console.log('disabledSwitch ' + disabledSwitch);

        $(".blogLike").attr('disabled', disabledSwitch);

        if (disabledSwitch == false )
        {
            console.log('True');
            $(".blogLike").color('green');
        }
    }

    function SetDisLike(disabledSwitch) {
        //alert('Here at SetDisLike');
        console.log('Here at SetDisLike');
        console.log('disabledSwitch ' + disabledSwitch);

        $(".blogDisLike").attr('disabled', disabledSwitch);

        if (disabledSwitch == false)
        {
            console.log('True');
            $(".blogDisLike").color('green');
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

The code executes but the boolean values are False instead of false. Yet the model screen shot above shows them as false.

JavaScript needs them to be false. Why is this happening and how to fix?

[image]

Comment: clearly, `@Model.LikeDisabled` and `@Model.DisLikeDisabled` are strings like False or True ... you could do something like `SetLike('@Model.LikeDisabled' === 'True');` - alternatively ... `const False=false, True=true;` then `SetLike(@Model.LikeDisabled)` - note the lack of `' '`

Comment: Ok..but the Model shows them as a value of false (see screen shot above'. How did they become a value of False?

Comment: Which screenshot shows that? Oh, nevermind, I see now ... the second screenshot is so full of errors it's a wonder anything is running at all

Comment: Yeah, I know...those are all library issues. Not my custom code. I added the model used too.

Comment: Please refer below https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491334/why-does-boolean-tostring-output-true-and-not-true

Comment: [Please refer below link for the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491334/why-does-boolean-tostring-output-true-and-not-true)

Comment: Jaomanda...how do I give you credit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like .NET is returning them as strings: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.boolean?view=netcore-3.1

in javascript, `'False' !== false`

@jaromanda-x's comment will be the right way to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

As per the second screen shot, the value passed by `@Model.LikeDisabled` is False, which is a string and not `false`which is the boolean property. I would recomend you to validate the properties before hand storing them in variables and then setting the `SetLike('@Model.LikeDisabled')` with the variable.

```
var like;
if('@Model.LikeDisabled' === 'False') {
    like = false;
} else { like = true; }
SetLike(like)
```

and the same for the dislike property.